# webpack module function not found

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a simple project with a few html files in root folder and a few javascript modules in scripts directory.

I want to start using webpack now because I want minification and to start using environments. Everything was working before I started using webpack.

I read documentation for Webpack 5 but could not find anything that solves my problem. So I came up with this webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        lib: "./scripts/lib.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
    inline: true, //Enable watch and live reload
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080,
    stats: "errors-only",
    https: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "index.html",
      hash: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My index.html imports and uses module functions like this:

```
<script type="module">
    import * as lib from "./scripts/lib.js";
    window.lib = lib;
</script>

<body onload="lib.myFn()">
</body>
```

But after running this webpack (using `webpack serve`) I am getting "is not a function" or "module not found" errors.

How can I compile and run my existing project with webpack without making any changes in my directory structure and fix this error so I can start using functions in lib.js in my index.html? Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like you should not be looking to import lib from scripts/lib.js, just ./lib.js maybe?

You should be importing it from the destination and not the source location.

Comment: (I converted my answer into a comment since I only really had half the answer, and maybe somebody else is more likely to see this if it has 0 answers)